# Fancybox not working, how to get Overlay to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm not sure why my fancybox isn't working, I have *jQuery*, *fancybox.css* and *fancybox.js* but I haven't been able to work.  I also can't seem to understand how to get the overlay to show up:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/ac5nxsup/1/

```js
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section1{
  background:red;
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<div class="section1">12</div>
<div class="section2"></div>
<div class="section3"></div>
<div class="section4"></div>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="fancy-about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references are the problem. When you run your demo you can see errors in the `console`:

> https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>
> https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

That's because the server blocks your request.

To solve this issue just replace the references to a normal CDN like **cdnjs**.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

And the working demo:

```js
$('.section1').click(function(){
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#fancy-about',
    helpers : {
      overlay : {
        css : {
          'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section1{
  background:red;
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<div class="section1">12</div>
<div class="section2"></div>
<div class="section3"></div>
<div class="section4"></div>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="fancy-about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/xutove/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Thanks but why doesn't it work the overlay work in my fiddle?

Comment: I don't understand the question.. `why doesn't it work the overlay work` Is the question why it works? or why it didn't?

Comment: Sorry, it was late last night lol..I meant why doesn't the overlay work in my jsfiddle even though I have seem to have the same code as the answer you provided.

Comment: Realy?! it's interesting.. Because `fancybox` is one of the most used plugin for lightbox and it's weird that they don't update their code. By the way, when you say `new jqueries` do you mean version `3`? because it's still in `alpha` state (as far I know, you can't find it in the [`download`](http://jquery.com/download/) page in the website)

Comment: I tested it with alpha, and 2 older versions before that on jsfiddle and it didn't work out for me but 2.1.3 worked I believe

Comment: That's exactly the result of my tests. Hopefully `fancybox` team will fix this.